# Как достать текст из файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

У меня есть файл `txt`:

```
печать( тест )
```

Как мне в `Python 3` достать `тест`?

Comment: прочитать файл `.txt`

Comment: Он выводит всю строку, а мне нужно только то что в нутри.

Comment: кто такой `он` ? Что значит `всю строку,` ? и `внутри` чего ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

с помощью регулярных выражений

```
import re

with open("file_name", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:  # заменить file_name на имя файла

    txt = file.read()

    txt = re.sub(r"\s", "", txt)

    out_txt = re.split(r"[()]", txt)

    print(out_txt[1])
```

Comment: Спасибо большое очень помог!

Comment: зачем вам это было нужно?) у меня нет идей)

Comment: был бы рад, если бы вы поставили upvote

Comment: Стоит файл закрыть всё же

Comment: @вася спасибо, забыл. исправлено

Comment: @Буднипрограммиста, если вам помог этот ответ, пожалуйста, не забудьте [проголосовать и отметить ответ как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)